# How do I find all the hosts in a local network?

Tags: tcp, multicast, bonjour, upnp

I would like to do it with the Reliability of a TCP Unicast.

I have used UPnP based Multicast (M-Search) but many devices filter out Multicast messages so I end up losing them.

Also, how does Bonjour compare to UPnP?

Comment: It isn't very clear what you're trying to do.  Or why.  Can you reword your question to better explain what you're searching for (every device on your network or some subset?) and what you plan to do with the search results please?  More detail on your unicast comment would be good too (or did you just mean "I find multicast unreliable and want something better"?)

Comment: Hi simonc, thank you for your response. Yes, I find multicast unreliable. Some phones and Routers completely block multicast for example. I'm searching for every device in a subnet. For example, if the Access Point gives out IP address in hte 192.168.2.X range, I want to know all the addresses assigned under 'X' in the subnet.

Answer (score 0):

For the second question
: In aspect of the functionality and reliability, uPnP and Bonjour are very similiar. The main difference of them is how prescriptive is. uPnP is more prescriptive.

Comment: Ok, I was hoping Bonjour would be more reliable. I'm not really looking to use any UPnP or Bonjour service. I just want a means to find hosts in a subnet reliably.